How to specify multiple entrypoints in Vite with Nuxt.JS
We're in the process of migrating our code over from a pure webpack/typescript/node model to using Nuxt.JS. Originally, for our backend we have 3 processes (4 including main) that were run concurrently using node's child process functionality. Here's an example of what that looked like:
webpack.config.server.dev.js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: {
    main: ['./src/server/app.ts'],
    process1: ['./src/server/process1.ts'],
    process2: ['./src/server/process2.ts'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  }
}

app.ts
*some import statements*

*some variables and logic*

const process1 = cp.fork(
    path.resolve(__dirname, "process1"),
    [],
    {}
);

const process2 = cp.fork(
    path.resolve(__dirname, "process2"),
    [],
    {}
);

Where processs1.ts and process2.ts are similar, standalone parts of code that do their own thing.
To run them as modules, we have webpack set up to create multiple entry points by bundling the .ts files into js files which can then be run using the cp.fork() function.
The issue is I'm not sure how to replicate this fucntionality in Nuxt with Vite.
Currently we have it setup so that in the nuxt.config.ts file we use a hook to listen for, and startup, the server. Example shown below:
import startServer from "./server";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...
  hooks: { listen: (server) => startServer(server) },
  ...
}

Which uses the index.ts (shown below) file within the server directory to allow us to run node code.
import { Server as NuxtServer } from 'node:http';

export default (nuxtServer: NuxtServer) => {
  console.info("NODE SERVER STARTS HERE!"); 
};

Initially I tried to get the app.ts function being called from here as that is the main driver for the other 3 processes.
index.ts
import { Server as NuxtServer } from 'node:http';

export default (nuxtServer: NuxtServer) => {
  console.info("CREATING SOCKET...");

  let appts = require("./app.ts");
  appts();
};

This runs and gives us a console log statement from within the app.ts file so thats working. We are, however, getting an error now at the path.resolve(__dirname, "process1") from the app.ts file as it doesnt recognise that module name. I tried changing it to path.resolve(__dirname, "process1.ts") however that gives an error stating cannot use import statement outside a module.
I looked into vite and how to bundle it for our needs and came across this quesiton (Multiple entry points in Vite) and tried variations of that but none of them work. I think the issue is that those are for html pages in the frontend and not ts files on the backend.
One last important note is that I took the compiled process1.js file from our previous codebase and put it in the directory manually and changed the path resolution to be path.resolve(__dirname, "process1.tjs") and it ran as expected.
Any ideas how I can get this to work?
